# Is it possible to successfully mine Unicoins on iOS?

Tags: bug, status-completed, unicoins, ios

I tried to do some Unicoin mining on the desktop site on my iPad, but had no success.  As I tap as fast as I can (need to tap slower than a double-tap), the rocks all turn to green goo and fade away.

Is it possible to mine Unicoins on iOS? (I imagine this would be a problem under other mobile OSes, but lack access to them to test.)

Comment: It works fine in Chrome on Android.

Comment: I think this is getting downvotes because the April fools joke is getting rolled out in a timezone-sensitive manner. (I'm not seeing anything here at least)

Comment: Anyone can change their system time zone to Indian time to see it now.

Comment: You need a case-sensitive Universal Zone Zip Idempotent (UZZI) widget first. These are available at your local chakra-dispenser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just fixed this, should work now. Try again?

Comment: Yup working like a charm 

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, in the same way that emulating Android on top of iOS is possible.

Comment: I have always wanted to do just that, and I believe I will

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider investing in a unicorn mining machine, I suspect there will be several apps released for this tomorrow.

A dedicated unicorn mining machine should be much more efficient at mining unicorns then using the iOS and android apps.

Comment: I'm not using the app. I'm browsing the desktop site in a browser.